# How to convert Map value using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a task:
Return a map of companies, where the key is its name and the value is a list of employees stored as String consisting of `firstName` and `lastName` separated by space.
Here is my solution and its works fine:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> getUserPerCompanyAsString() {
        return getCompanyStream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Company::getName, company ->  getUserNames(company.getUsers())));
    }

    private List<String> getUserNames(List<User> users) {
        return users.stream()
                .map(user -> user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

public class Company {
    private final String name;
    private final List<User> users;
}

public class User {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final Sex sex;
    private final int age;
    private final List<Account> accounts;
    private final List<Permit> permits;
}
```

So my question, how to convert `List<User>` as map value to `List<String>` with `firstName` and `lastName` separated by space in one stream chain without helper method?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to move the code in the helper method directly into the value lambda :) - I just have the feeling you don't want to do that.

Comment: So not adding a `String getFullName()` method to class `User`? You're already using a lambda expression... can you clarify what you have in mind?

Comment: Note that since your first stream is a stream of `Company` objects you want to collect and the values should be a converted property of each key element (the company), you need that conversion code - so `company.getUsers().stream().map(...).collect(...)` is what you need anyway. The only thing you've added is a readable method signature around this - why do you want to get rid if that?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks you, it's exactly what i need. 
I wanted get rid of helper method because i didn't understand that i can open stream in lambda, and was curious about way how to solve that task in different ways.

Comment: Ahhh, so you wanted to get rid of the `getUserNames` method.

Comment: Consider adding the solution as an answer and accepting it or simply deleting the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

Thanks to [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas) suggestion I'm able solve this problem without helper method:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> getUserPerCompanyAsString() {
        return getCompanyStream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Company::getName, company -> company.getUsers().stream()
                                .map(user -> user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I get that you want to get ride of the helper method.
A cleaner way would be to include the `getUserNames` method inside of `Company`, it makes more sense than to have this logic hanging inside of a `Collector`.

The solution would also be more readable

```
Map<String, List<String>> getUserPerCompanyAsString() {
    return getCompanyStream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Company::getName,
            Company::getUserNames
        )
    );
}



public class Company {
    private final String name;
    private final List<User> users;

    // Constructor making sure users is not null

    private List<String> getUserNames() {
        return this.users
                   .stream()
                   .map(User::getFullName)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

public class User {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    
    // Etc.

    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: @YashRami your edit is wrong !